# centralizer of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory

Is there any specification around the centralizer(or Normalizer) of a cyclic subgroup of General linear group over finite field?even with some conditions, for example when cyclic group is irreducible.

Comment: If it's irreducible, then the centralizer in ${\rm GL}(n,q)$ is cyclic of order $q^n-1$ (generated by a Singer cycle), and the normalizer is the group ${\rm AGL}(1,q^n)$ of order $(q^n-1)n$.

Comment: So for a primitive cyclic subgroup of $GL(n,q)$ it s centralizer is equal to itself?. Is there any reference for more information?

Comment: What do you mean by primitive?

Comment: I mean, a cyclic subgroup of $GL(n,q)$ which its generator is a companion matrix of a primitive poly of degree $n$ over $F_q$

Comment: That is very confusing, because a primitive matrix group is a standard concept and means something completely different. I think what you say is equivalent to the cyclic group having order $q^n-1$, and such subgroups are self-centralizing.

Comment: yes, I meant a cyclic group of order $q^n-1$, and I got my answer. Thank you

Comment: typo: Normalizer is $\Gamma L(1,q^n)$ of order $(q^n-1)n$

Comment: If the cyclic group is not irreducible, or in general, is there any work about the centralizer of cyclic subgroups of General linear group $GL(n,q)$?

Comment: If the cyclic group is semi-simple things are pretty easy: basically just what Derek said, but with some messiness for repeated factors. If the cyclic group has order $k$ and $\gcd(k,q) \neq 1$, I think things are a much bigger pain.